# Does PHP cache includes at run time?

Tags: php

I am including the same files multiple times on the same page. I noticed when I do this, it seems PHP is caching the files. When I generate a random number with the rand function, it is the same in both includes. Anyone know how I can stop PHP from doing this? I tried some different header functions like this but they don't work:

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); // always modified
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP/1.0
```

Edit: Ok, I'm dumb and I forgot that I was calling the includes from a jquery script which I believe is caching the files. I went back to see the code some one was asking for and noticed it. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Where are your include()? Show us some more code...

Comment: I am including two files that output rand()

Comment: Are you salting the random number generator?

Comment: header function is to control the header from the file, to the browser don't cache it, it will not work in your includes.....

Comment: I have tried salting it and I have tried mt_rand. They all produce the same output in both includes.

Comment: try to run your PHP files from console, and check again, maybe your server is sabotaging your results.

Comment: @Keith: You ask a question about include() function, but refuse to show us the code where you used include(). Do you expect us to guess what your code is?

Comment: The include files contain echo 'number: '. rand();  The files that are calling the include files contain include 'thefile.php'; include 'thefile.php';

Comment: Salting is __not__ a good idea. If you salt the random number generator with the same value each time it is used, it will generate the same results. These days (and for many years now) the random number generator is salted already with values that don't have this effect

Comment: I tried salting it with the current time as well as not salting it at all.

Comment: @GabrielGartz require() and include() both are not functions. They are both just language constructs. They never return TRUE or FALSE on success respectively. Even if you try to include the file that doesn't exists it WILL never return FALSE. Also we can use them without parentheses

Comment: @metal_fan sorry, but where did I sad that it was a function? I have only mentioned header function. I think you was talking about Jocelyn comment.

Comment: @GabrielGartz oh sorry for this, you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that including the same file multiple times is not particularly good practice.

A better solution would be to include it once, and call the functions it contains multiple times.

Obviously, this will mean changing the way the code works -- I guess it's currently written as a block of code that is run as soon as it it included. You'd need to change it so that it's enclosed in a function (or several functions, as required) so that it can be called at will.

Then just include it once at the start of your program.

I know this doesn't directly answer the question, but doing it this way is better coding practice, and will make your code much easier to manage and maintain.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I agree and I might change it to work that way but I'm also interested if it's caching. I read somewhere that all variables in includes are read into namespace and aren't accessed again. I can't find anywhere else that says this though.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you're seeding the pRNG with the same value within that file. Headers affect the browser, not the script anyway.

I know for certain that included files are not cached: I made a console program where every "function" was implemented by including a file. Changing the file without restarting the program still allowed it to load the updated files.

So, your problem is either the random seed, or something elsewhere. Try `echo microtime()` to see if it gives the same result both times.

Comment: microtime produced the same output from all the includes (0.83720300 1340651830)